# Import cucumber step definitions of one module into another maven module

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I have the following Maven project structure with Junit and Cucumber:

```
| root project
    | Module 1
         | src
             | main
             | test
                 | java
                     | tests // where all step definitions from Module 1 are stored
             | resources
                 | features // feature files from Module 1
    | Module 2
         | src
             | main
             | test
                 | java
                     | tests // where all step definitions from Module 2 are stored
             | resources
                 | features // feature files from Module 2
```

I want to reuse the steps from Module 1 in Module 2. Is it possible to import step definitions from Module 1 to Module 2 to reuse them there?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Depends on whether you have taken some trials on your own already?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to add Module1 as a dependency for Module2 and set the 'glue' in the cucumber runner class, but it still was throwing the 'UndefinedStepException' exception.

Also, I've found in some other place, that exporting the steps defs into the separate jar file may help, but not sure if it's a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are already doing is kind of correct approach. You need to consider the following:

1. Since your Step Defs are in `test` the are not transitively take part in `module2` class path
2. Make also sure there that the step defs in module1 are in a proper package relationships to your `module2`: your runner class in `module2` is in the same package or above than your feature file which is in the same package or above than your step definition class
3. Make sure that `module2` has `module1` as a dependency

So to remediate point 1 in your example you need to move your step definition in `module1` from `test` to `main`

Comment: It's also possible to use `test-jar` to build a jar with the test classes in it

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html